# How to share state between two monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I am stuck with following monad problem:

Let's say I have a standard monad State with state S = (LS, RS). I also have another monad:

```
newtype StateP a = StateP {runP :: S -> (a, RS)}
```

I want to perform some computation using StateP then merge state with state in State monad:

```
merge m :: StateP() -> State()
merge m = do
 s@(l,r) <- get
 put (l, snd (runP m s))
```

It is not working, but I don't get why? Is there another way to achieve such functionality?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Do you get compile errors (what are they?) or does it fail at runtime? The `merge` code you've posted looks like it shouldn't compile --- is it your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use monad transformers to model these requirements more explicitly using two monad stacks: one that can only read `LS` and one that can both read and write `LS`.

```
type ReadOnlyLS a  = ReaderT LS (State RS) a
type ReadWriteLS a = StateT LS (State RS) a
```

To run a `ReadOnlyLS` within `ReadWriteLS`, we just need to extract `LS` from the outermost state layer, give it to the reader layer of the inner computation and lift the resulting computation back into the outer monad:

```
merge :: ReadOnlyLS a -> ReadWriteLS a
merge m = get >>= lift . runReaderT m
```

Answer (score 2):

On the off-chance that your code is nearly right, try

```
merge :: StateP() -> State()
merge m = do
    s@(l,r) <- get
    put (l, snd (runP m s))
```

But you need to give us more details really.

Comment: Hey. It is actually working. I can't really say why I got some type errors before. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Oh looks like you didn't have `do`.

Comment: it was not missing. i think i might wrote fst instead of snd. anyway it should be marked for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

How do you achieve the functionality of RunP? Do you redefine a monad instance for it and have getP/putP? Your code seems fine, can you provide the m you use? What kind of misbehaviour do you get?

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Well, it was a stub for answer - I planned to edit it as soon as the author adds more details.